# Xepersian inverse decimal numbers with period (.)

Tags: tables, xepersian

For example 2.41 becomes 41.2

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[format=hang, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont[Scale=2]{Times New Roman}
\setlatintextfont[Scale=2]{Times New Roman}
\defpersianfont\Sayeh[Scale=1.5]{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{Add caption}
\begin{tabular}{rrl}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{النسبة (\%)}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{المساحة (كام²)}} & \textbf{الجماعة} \\
\midrule
    2.41                 & 4.22                 & زريزر \\
    3.79                 & 6.66                 & خلالفة \\
    26.51                & 46.56                & مزراوة \\
\midrule
\textbf{100.00}      & \textbf{175.65}      & \textbf{المجموع} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `xepersian` package (at the `end of` your package), your text will be written right to left.
But for decimal number this structure will change (This is intentional; for example,  it is used for the chapters numbering and also equation numbering ...).
The xepersian package have a nice command for this situation. you should use `\setlatin` command for this purpose.
And also I use  `array` package for extended `column definitions`.
This is your codes:

---

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[format=hang, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}% for extended column definitions 
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont[Scale=2]{Times New Roman}
\setlatintextfont[Scale=2]{Times New Roman}
\defpersianfont\Sayeh[Scale=1.5]{Times New Roman}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{Add caption}
\begin{tabular}{>{\setlatin}r>{\setlatin}r>{\setlatin}l}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{النسبة (\%)}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{المساحة (كام²)}} & \textbf{الجماعة} \\
\midrule
2.41 
& 
4.22                
& زريزر \\
    3.79                 & 6.66                 & خلالفة \\
    26.51                & 46.56                & مزراوة \\
\midrule
\textbf{100.00}      & \textbf{175.65}      & \textbf{المجموع} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

---

And this is your output:

---

### [image]

Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

Using XePersian your decimal numbers will get messed up.
You have 3 options:

1. Type numbers inversed (Not recommended)
2. Put your number in math inline mode, `$ $`
3. Use Persian/Arabic decimal point instead of `.`

---

```
    \documentclass{article} 
    \usepackage{xepersian} 
    \settextfont{Yas}
    \setdigitfont{Yas}

    \begin{document}
        \centering
        اعداد \\
        12.75\\
        75.12\\
        $12.75$\\
        12٫75 % type ٫ using  SHIFT+3 (Persian standard keyboard) or SHIFT+k (Arabic keyboard)
    \end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: This is kind of workaround but does not solve the problem, for a small table it is ok, but when we have a a big table with many rows and sells, it is not ok, it becomes a big problem when we use Excel2LaTx, i am going to accept your answer.